does 24.04 LTS include support for ethernet over usb
I’m trying to configure a connection between a raspberry pi 4 running ubuntu 24.04 connected to an ipad pro.
It has been known to work in the past but I cannot get it to work with 24.04.
I have not been able to find references to usbnet or any usb? device in the context of 24.04.
============ update ===============
I think I have found a solution path!
In searching I have found
USB/IP as an option
there’s a lot of detail I don’t yet understand.
does anyone know how this works?
Thanks
Phil
